# appending html after the last image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i append the following html after the last img:

```
//create the icon
$('div.lookup-image-wrapper > div img').append('<div class="icon"></div>');
```

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="lookup-image-wrapper" style="text-align: center">

        <div class="divProductPic" id="divProductPic26039">
            <img alt="200 D" border="0" id="ProductPic26039" name=
            "ProductPic26039" onclick="popuplarge_26039()" src=
            "images/Product/medium/26039.jpg" style=
            "cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;" title=
            "Click here to view larger image">
        </div>


    <img alt="Show Picture 1" border="0" class="image-nav" onclick="_(1);" src="images/PRODUCT/icon/26039_1_.jpg"
        style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">
    <img alt="Show Picture 2" border="0" class="image-nav" onclick="_(2);" src="images/PRODUCT/icon/26039_2_.jpg"
         style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;"><img alt="Show Picture 3" border="0" class="image-nav" onclick="setcolorpicidx_26039(3);" src=
        "images/PRODUCT/icon/26039_3_.jpg" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">

            <!--[#### THE DIV ICON NEEDS TO GO HERE #####]-->

     <div id="prodEmbiggen">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=""><img align="absmiddle" alt="" border="0" src="showlarger.gif" title=
          "Click for larger image"></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use the :last or .last() selector on image tags then .append() http://api.jquery.com/last/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div.lookup-image-wrapper > img:last').after('<div class="icon"></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems to add it to the last div, inside the A because that would be the last image: http://jsfiddle.net/x6Yrr/1/

Comment: Which image are you trying to target? The one inside `.divProductPic`?

Comment: yep... i need to add the HTML before the `<div id="prodEmbiggen">`

Comment: I fixed it, i think you needed `$('div.lookup-image-wrapper > div > img:last').after('<div class="icon"></div>');`

Answer (score 2):

To append content after the last image, use the last selector (:last)

```
$('div.lookup-image-wrapper > div img:last').append("your content");
```

If you have a lot of content to append, you can minify the HTML here http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/